# Kubuntu : impossible to display R shiny in external window

Tags: kubuntu, r

I hope I'm in the right place for this question.

I wrote a Shiny App with R Shiny but when I want to run the app in a external window, there's an error message from KIOExec saying (in French) : "Un dossier nommé /home/myname/.cache/kioexec/krun/28025_0/ existe déjà" which in English is basically : "A folder named /home/myname/.cache/kioexec/krun/28025_0/ already exists".

My laptop runs with Kubuntu 18.04.02 LTS, maybe it is important in order to fix this.

For now, I tried to go in /home/myname/.cache/kioexec/krun/ and it appears that there are about 40 folders and many are empty but other are not so I prefer not to delete all of them without knowing what they are.

Does somebody have a solution ?

Comment: Debugging your app isn't really on-topic here.  Stack Overflow would probably be a better fit, but people will need to see what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it thanks to : https://www.progclub.org/blog/2018/12/14/a-folder-named-cache-kioexec-krun-13821_0-already-exists/

Here's the part that I did : 
"I solved the issue (for me) by changing:

System Settings -> Personalization -> Applications -> Default Application s-> Web Browser

from:

Open http and https URLs in an application based on the contents of the URL

to:

Open http and https URLs in the following browser: firefox"

thanks anyway